# Adding 30 days to date giving one day less

Tags: java

I am adding 30 days to a date but its giving me 1 day less.

i.e. if I put 20 oct 2011 then it is giving 19 Nov 2011 one day less .

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: October has 31 days.  This answer is expected.

Comment: can you post the code
it should be an easy fix if your using count or ++i
it always one less i < 30 the count starts a 0 so it will only count up to 29

Answer (score 6):

There are 31 days in October, so the software is correct. If you're trying to add one month, add one month and not thirty days.

Comment: Right, and it should be done in Joda Time using [plusMonths](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusMonths(int))

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you count the number of days in [October](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October).